# Azure Storage Explorer - Is it possible to change access tier at the directory level for files copied to Data Lake

Tags: azure, storage, coolstorage

Trying to figure out how to change the access tier to cold for directories we'd like to store in a hot data lake container. It appears the only option is to change the access tier on a file by file basis as directories and files will inherit the Data Lake's preferred access tier option selected when it was created. Would it be possible to override this setting in one container to cool or archive?
Can the data be transferred as "cool" using azcopy or Storage Explorer.
The other option would be to set a Lifecycle Management Policy on the storage account, selecting only the container in question and changing the access tier after 1 day or so.
Would like to avoid that approach if there is a simpler solution.
The end goal is to have a simple archival strategy that takes files to cool storage using the existing data lake.

Answer (score 1):

One of the workarounds is to navigate to your **storage account >> Right click on your directory >> Change Access tier >> Cool**.

[image]

[image]

**RESULTS:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that is one way to do it from Storage Explorer.  Would it be better to use a lifecycle management policy? I'm trying the following policy in the hopes that it will move all files in that container to archive tier after one day but it's not working. I've set the selection criteria "after one day of not being used".

Comment: Here's the json code :{
  "rules": [
    {
      "enabled": true,
      "name": "move to cool storage",
      "type": "Lifecycle",
      "definition": {
        "actions": {
          "baseBlob": {
            "tierToArchive": {
              "daysAfterLastAccessTimeGreaterThan": 1
            }
          }
        },
        "filters": {
          "blobTypes": [
            "blockBlob"
          ],
          "prefixMatch": [
            "/amcont1"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}

Comment: I'm checking the container after one day and two days and nothing has changed, the access tier still remains the same. Is there a way to test this interactively?